# I have a tab bar that I am trying to detect if it was touched inside view controller 2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Basically I have a tab bar in view controller one. I am trying to detect if this tabaritem is touched inside view controller 2. What is the best method to perform such a task? I can post more specific code if you would like.

view controller 1

```
  TUHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[TUHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
homeNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[DSTabBarItem alloc] initWithFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"] 
                                                            finishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home1"]
                                                                                 iconSize:CGSizeMake(76, 59)
                                                                                tag:0];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:homeNavigationController];
```

view controller 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UITabBarControllerDelegate.  See:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

More specifically, look at

```
tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

"Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar."

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate didselectviewcontroller and put delegate of tabbarcobtroller to self