# what am i doing wrong with the tab bar delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I took some advice from the previous questions and modify the code quite a bit.I am still trying to detect when a tab bar item is being touched.If the selected index is zero is should return "moo" in nslog.I might be missing a minor detail.

view controller 1

```
     TUHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[TUHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
homeNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[DSTabBarItem alloc] initWithFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"] 
                                                            finishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home1"]
                                                                                 iconSize:CGSizeMake(76, 59)
                                                                                tag:0];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:homeNavigationController];
```

view controller 2.h

```
     @interface viewcontroller2 : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>{

       }
```

view controller 2

```
   - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"MOO");
 return(TRUE);

}
return(FALSE);
 }

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
   self.delegate = self;
   }
```

Comment: whats the value of self.tabBarController.selectedIndex  or its not triggering ?

Comment: Why create an additional question?  Update your post and continue in your original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504349/i-have-a-tab-bar-that-i-am-trying-to-detect-if-it-was-touched-inside-view-contro

Comment: Please show where you've set up UITabBarControllerDelegate

Comment: updated the code for you.

Comment: Is ir even going to the delegate.keep breakpoint and check and if not plz set the delegate to self and one more thing why r u using self.tabbar

Answer (score 0):

Set your delegate to self:

```
[tabBarViewControllers setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement your tabBar delegate in appdelegare(where you are creating)

```
self.objTabBarController.delegate=self;
```

And implement its delegate method in appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"MOO");
    return YES;
}
```